# blockarray Size of Brackets

Tags: math-mode, block

Is there a way to increase the size of the brackets when using blockarray and block? Please see the example below:

```
\begin{align*}
    \begin{blockarray}{l c c c c}
                            &   A   &   B   &   C   &   D   \\
    \begin{block}{l [c c c c]}
        \ce{B2D}\;({\#}225) &   225 &   2       &   0       &   1   \\
        \ce{B2D2}\;({\#}194)    &   194 &   2       &   0       &   2   \\
        \ce{C2D}\;({\#}225)  &  225 &   0       &   2       &   1   \\
        \ce{CD3}\;({\#}44)  &   44  &   0       &   1       &   3   \\
    \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
\end{align*}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the brackets aren't big enough.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I already noted this problem. You can try adding an invisible rule  upwards in the first row, and a negative one (downwards) in the last one.

Comment: Bernard. I tried adding a \rule with 0 width in different locations, but nothing happened. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. Could you please give me more details on how to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a workaround: with the `bigstrut` package, I define a `topstrut` and a `\botstrut` commands, to incorporate in the first and last lines of a `block` respectively. Their lengths can be adjusted in the preamble, and, if your tables have always the same structure, you might  create a new personal environment that incorporates them.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\topstrut[1][1.2ex]{\setlength\bigstrutjot{#1}{\bigstrut[t]}}
\newcommand\botstrut[1][0.9ex]{\setlength\bigstrutjot{#1}{\bigstrut[b]}}

\\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
  \begin{blockarray}{l c c c c}
                       & A & B & C & D \\[-0.6ex]
  \begin{block}{l [c c c c]}
  \ce{B2D}\;({\#}225) & 225 & 2 & 0 & 1\topstrut \\
  \ce{B2D2}\;({\#}194) & 194 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
  \ce{C2D}\;({\#}225) & 225 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
  \ce{CD3}\;({\#}44) & 44 & 0 & 1 & 3 \botstrut \\
  \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the tools of `nicematrix`, the brackets will be, by default, a bit bigger.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}  

\begin{align*}
    \begin{NiceArray}{l \left[c c c c\right]}[first-row]
                            &   A   &   B   &   C   &   D   \\
        \ce{B2D}\;({\#}225) &   225 &   2       &   0       &   1   \\
        \ce{B2D2}\;({\#}194)    &   194 &   2       &   0       &   2   \\
        \ce{C2D}\;({\#}225)  &  225 &   0       &   2       &   1   \\
        \ce{CD3}\;({\#}44)  &   44  &   0       &   1       &   3   \\
    \end{NiceArray}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]